# Find the closest named color

Tags: javascript, performance, json, typescript

I have a .json file with name (string) and RGB (r, g, b: numbers) with 30.000 key-value pairs. I am looping the json multiple times per second to find the closest name to a given RGB color. Any idea how I can optimize the code or the json data to make it faster? Currently it works fine for the few calls per seconds, but after 30-50 calls per seconds there is noticeable lag.

```
[
 { "name": "Aare River", "rgb": { "r": 0, "g": 184, "b": 159 } },
 { "name": "Aare River Brienz", "rgb": { "r": 5, "g": 163, "b": 173 } },
 { "name": "Aarhusian Sky", "rgb": { "r": 17, "g": 80, "b": 175 } },
 { "name": "Abaddon Black", "rgb": { "r": 35, "g": 31, "b": 32 } },
]
```

```
fetch("/data/colorsNames.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    colorsNames = data;
  });

function setColorName(color: string): void {
  let closestColor = findClosestColorName(hexToRgb(color, false) as ColorRGB);
  colorNameText.textContent = colorsNames[closestColor[0]].name;
}


function findClosestColorName(
  color: ColorRGB
): [index: number, distance: number] {
  let closestIndex = -1;
  let closestDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  let distance = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  for (let i = 0; i < colorsNames.length; i++) {
    distance = getColorsDistance(color, colorsNames[i].rgb);

    if (distance < closestDistance) {
      closestIndex = i;
      closestDistance = distance;
    }

    if (closestDistance === 0) return [closestIndex, closestDistance];
  }

  return [closestIndex, closestDistance];

  function getColorsDistance(color: ColorRGB, match: ColorRGB): number {
    return (
      Math.abs(color.r - match.r) +
      Math.abs(color.g - match.g) +
      Math.abs(color.b - match.b)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes the purpose of the code rather than its mechanism, per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask). Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: If you're willing to pull in an external dependency (or write it yourself) you can use an octree. E.g. [d3-octree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-octree).

Comment: If someone wants to test this code or alternatives, there is a library at https://github.com/meodai/color-names which contains around 30000 color names.

Comment: Yeah, this is the library I use, I converted the hex codes to RGB.

Answer (score 5):

### Incorrect calculation of color distance

#### sRGB is a logarithmic scale

RGB (AKA [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB)) as used by the browser is a logarithmic scale (apart from the very darker values which are linear)

Your calculation of color distance does not take this into account and results in a bias towards darker colors.

A quick and good approximation for color values is to raise each channels' value to 2.2 and then calculate the distance.

#### Use pythagoras for distance

The distance between colors is not the sum of the differences between channels, it is the square root of the sum of the square differences (ie pythagoras).

Thus and example of calculating the color distance.

Example

```
  function getColorsDistance(color: ColorRGB, match: ColorRGB): number {
    var r = (color.r ** 2.2) - (match.r ** 2.2);
    var g = (color.g ** 2.2) - (match.g ** 2.2);
    var b = (color.b ** 2.2) - (match.b ** 2.2);
    return ((r * r + g * g + b * b) ** 0.5) ** (1 / 2.2);
  }
```

As you are interested in the relative distance (not the sRGB distance) one can skip the square root and the conversion to linear to get

```
  function getColorsNearness(color: ColorRGB, match: ColorRGB): number {
    var r = (color.r ** 2.2) - (match.r ** 2.2);
    var g = (color.g ** 2.2) - (match.g ** 2.2);
    var b = (color.b ** 2.2) - (match.b ** 2.2);
    return r * r + g * g + b * b;
  }
```

In terms of performance you can also store the colors in converted values saving the need to raise each channel to the power of 2.2 each time you test the distance.

For example a named color

```
{ name: "Aare River", rgb: { r: 0 ** 2.2, g: 184 ** 2.2, b: 159 ** 2.2 } },
```

#### [Exponentiation (**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) operator

Incase you are not familiar with the [** operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation). It is the same as `Math.pow`.

For example `Math.pow(10, 2.2) === 10 ** 2.2;`

To get the root use the inverse power.

For example `Math.sqrt(10) === 10 ** (1 / 2) === 10 ** 0.5`

### Search

The loop you use to find the closest color can be improved.

#### Use a `for of` loop

There is no need to use a counter `i` if you use a [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

#### Early exit

Move the early exit into the block that that sets `closestDistance` to a new value, this will save you many cycles.

The improved search would look like.

**Note** I changed the return type (assume you use an array lookup outside the function which is not needed if you have the color object) and function name to more closely match the functions behavior.

```
function findClosestColor(color: ColorRGB): [namedColor: ColorRGB, distance: number] {
  var closestColor: ColorRGB;
  var closestDistance = Infinity;
  for (const namedColor of colorsNames) {
    const distance = getColorsDistance(color, namedColor.rgb);
    if (distance < closestDistance) {   
      closestColor = namedColor;
      closestDistance = distance;
      if (closestDistance === 0) { break; }
    }
  }
  return [closestColor, closestDistance];
}
```

### Performance

You say

> *"Currently it works fine for the few calls per seconds, but after 30-50 calls per seconds there is noticeable lag"*

Unless you have a huge list of colors (There are 147 named HTML colors) or very slow device, the lag at 30 searches per second (One search > 16ms to create noticeable lag????) hints at another source of performance loss.

On an mid range PC (And using the sRGB logarithmic distance) I can search well over 10,000 colors from a list of 256 colors in under 16ms (Maintaining smooth 60FPS animation).

Your slowdown begins 4 orders of magnitude sooner using a simpler calculation, something else is going on as JavaScript is not that slow.

Comment: Just one little remark about the: _"Your slowdown begins 4 orders of magnitude sooner"_. That's a factor of 10.000, but I think you mean a factor of 4? After all 256 x 10.000 = 2.560.000 searches and 50 x 30.000 = 600.000 searches. A factor of 4 isn't all that much. Javascript can be quite slow sometimes, depending on the browser and device.

Comment: I use a list of 30.000 colors, the max distance from one color name to another is about 30/765 which I display it as a percentage (96%) so I don't think it's worth to use the logarithmic scale in this case.

Comment: @Relik8 I have no idea how you computed that. The total color space is 256 x 256 x 256 = 16,777,216 of which you've used 30,000. That's 0.18% of the total space. Or, if the colors are evenly spread they can occupy a cube of roughly 8 x 8 x 8 steps, but they're likely not evenly spread. I think that using the logarithmic scale, which is the correct way to do it, will have a visible impact. What about the other improvements to your code that Blandman67 proposes?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The job of `getColorsDistance` is to return the sum distance of the r, g, b channels (integers) of 2 RGB colors. I use this distance to display how close it is to the closest named color with this `(((765 - distance) / 765) * 100)` . I know 0 to 255 is 256*3=768 but again this is not what I want. Using `for of` instead of `for` is faster, but the difference is insignificant and I already exit early when distance is 0. The post is about making this faster by reducing the number of loops for `findClosestColorName` and this answer doesn't do that.

Comment: OK, no problem, of course you can choose your own [definition for color distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018016/how-to-compare-two-colors-for-similarity-difference). I agree that the difference between `for of` and `for` is minimal, however, the point where you exit the loop can make a difference. Have another look. You check `(closestDistance === 0)` every time, whereas Blandman67 only performs that check when `(distance < closestDistance)`. The latter will not be encountered very often.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes 4 orders of magnitude. OP notes lag at 30 searches per second. Assuming lag is < 60fps then OPs single search takes longer than 16ms. Test device can do 10000 searches in under 16ms. Hence 4 orders of magnitude slower, 30 searches per second compared to 10000 * 60 = 600000 searches per second before seeing lag. (Note I compare a my 256 color search against my estimate of OPs colors 1(47 named HTML colors). Now read (OMDG) OP has 30,000 named colors (never knew that many color names existed))

Comment: @Relik8 OK my BAD did not see you actually stated number of colors. Will need to revize my answer when I get a chance. Do you have a link to your list of named colors (if public or open source)

Comment: @Relik8 I will not revize answer as the best performance increase I can get is ~40% faster, which will not remove your lag for 50 colors (Plus I would be outside the topic of review). My advice is to use `webWorkers` to do the search as they can run concurrently (there own threads) leaving the main thread to do its thing (No lag at all)